# Normal Proxy Settings block OSM Tools Plugin

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, routing, proxy

I would like to know if there is a good workaround / solution for proxy settings in an work/ office environment?

More detailed, with usual proxy settings from our IT departement some plugins like OSM Tools don't work. It just goes to request the server but not further.
[image]
Our IT Deparment can't see any request to a server like the OSM layer does if you change the map extent or scale..

So, without proxy settings - everything just works fine. But because of reasons we need proxy, but it seems like QGIS does not fetch the user settings if user proxy settings are set.

To clarify:
[image: proxy settings]

Also it seems like different plugins use ways around the proxy settings or just ways that aren't visible for our IT departement. And because of that, they can't set them free to use.
[image]

thats how the stamen layer looks like with enabled proxy settings.

Comment: Have you set your proxy settings  in QGIS (Settings->Options->Network)?

Comment: yes. and we changed them very often during the last weeks, depending on different plugins which needed different settings. the main problem is, i guess, that there is not just one adress that needs a filter..

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Corporate networks usually have just one proxy for internet access. Why would you need different proxy settings for different plugins?

Comment: the problem is, that different proxy settings allow different plugins. i can load an osm layer but not stamen.. i can use online routing mapper but not osm tools to run a routing request.

Comment: You're not explaining why you need different settings, just restating that you do. Can you provide examples of the different settings? Edit your question, don't use comments to add the info.

Comment: It looks like the Stamen layer is added to the project OK but there is something wrong with the data. Are your projection settings right? I wonder what do you need to change with the proxy settings. There is not much to set, only proxy host and port.